# How can I get the signature of the update version of NuGet to match he installed version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im using Visual Wb Developer 2012 Express.  I'm trying to update NuGet.  Inside the error log i find this:

Install Error : VSIXInstaller.SignatureMismatchException: The signature on the update version of 'NuGet Package Manager' does not match the signature on the installed version. Therefore, Extension Manager cannot install the update.
   at VSIXInstaller.Common.VerifyMatchingExtensionSignatures(IInstalledExtension installedExtension, IInstallableExtension updateExtension)
   at VSIXInstaller.InstallProgressPage.BeginInstallVSIX(SupportedVSSKU targetAppID)

How can i get the signature of the  update version of NuGet to match he installed version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget's had some issues with upgrades requiring the user first uninstall the old addin, and then installing the new version fresh. Give that a shot. Upgrades after that *should* be ok.

Comment: Thanks I was afraid to uninstall and reinstall because it didn't work on my other windows 8 machine but it seems to work now on Windows 7.  Thanks!